# Long press event in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

is there a long press event on `sap.m.List` or `sap.m.Button`? 
I can't seem to find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently there is no support for this in the UI5 framework. But you can always implement it by yourself.

Comment: might it be possible to use jQuery's "taphold" ?

Comment: My idea is that it is not implemented in UI5 due to some framework specific issues concerning all use cases at the moment. You can definitely implement it and we have jQuery library as basis of the framework :)

Answer (score 1):

As kazandzhiro pointed out it is not part of the current API which is 1.36.10.

-- SPOILER --

But it will be available once SAPUI5 implements the SAP Fiori 2.0 Guidelines. SAP is currently finishing internal works on Fiori 2.0 and some of the new features and controls are already implemented.

You can find them in the new `sap.uxap.*` Package.

So stay aware...

Answer (score 0):

A long press event is currently not part of the ui5 framework.

You can look up the supported events in the [SAPUI5 Reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html).
Just search for `sap.m.Button` or `sap.m.List` and you can see the **Event Summary**.